# Best Practice: Managing string list with entity framework and migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've been searching for the best practice for managing/storing a list of strings in the database optional with entity framework, but migration should be supported.

E.g.
I have a list of city-names which I like to store in a new table. This table contains all available citys in my project.

I've a property City in a Address class, which address one of the citys in my City-Table.
1. Is it better to set a reference to the entry in the City-Table or apply and store the value in the Address - Table ?
2. What's the best practice for creating the City-Table? Generating a class City in my Model seems to be a little bit too much overhead, but where can I manage/create it if I like to reference the entries in the Address?

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to what your application will be able to do. If you are planning to do some operations with cities, it would be wise to have them as separeted entities. Otherwise, you would have to query the Address table, and group the cities (which will offer some troubles, like people entering "Moron" and "Morón" as cities, for example).

Comment: Not to mention having to maintain the list of cities as new ones incorporate, or existing ones merge.